# Calling odbc_fetch_array after executing a stored procedure in PHP gives error [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures, odbc

So, I'm trying to use ODBC to execute a stored procedure in an SQL database, but it returns the error

```
odbc_fetch_array() [function.odbc-fetch-array]: 
    SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid Descriptor Index, 
    SQL state S1002 in SQLGetData
```

Here's the PHP part, pretty standard

```
...
$id = 240

$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$server = "server";
$database = "database";

$con = odbc_connect("SERVER=$server; 
                     DRIVER=SQL Server;
                     DATABASE=$database", 
                     $user, 
                     $password);    

$res = odbc_exec($con, "exec usp_GetRelatedToID '$id'");

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Here's the Stored Procedure, really small and easy

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetRelatedToID]
    @id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT AMENDMENT_ID, WDATE, ALTERATION, VER, REASON
    FROM AMENDMENTS
    WHERE AMENDMENT_ID = $id
END
```

Here's the Table schema for AMENDMENTS

```
(Column_name)      (Type)        (Nullable)
AMENDMENT_ID        int             no
RAD_MAIN_ID         int             yes
WDATE               datetime        yes
USR_ID              int             yes
ALTERATION          varchar         yes
REASON              varchar         yes
VER                 int             yes

Identity        Seed   Increment   Not For Replication
AMENDMENT_ID      1        1               0

constraint_type               constraint_name      constraint_keys
PRIMARY KEY (non-clustered) aaaaaAMENDMENTS1_PK      AMENDMENT_ID
```

**What's interesting is that it doesn't return the error if I remove the column `VER` from the procedure**

Like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetRelatedToID]
    @id int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT AMENDMENT_ID, WDATE, ALTERATION, REASON
    FROM AMENDMENTS
    WHERE AMENDMENT_ID = $id
END
```

Can anyone explain where I'm doing wrong and why this keep happening? I've got other stored procedures that give the same errors (some also share the column `VER`), and I've got stored procedures that don't.

I've tried different methods of fetching the data in PHP using `odbc_prepare` and `odbc_execute` with both query structures, `{CALL usp_GetRelatedToID(?)}`, but that just gave me more errors.

And for reasons I won't go into, I can't use mssql functions in PHP, ODBC is the only way I'm allowed to connect and query.

**Oh, and executing the plain (original) query instead of in a stored procedure gives no errors.**

**EDIT**

```
$stmt = odbc_prepare($con, "{CALL usp_GetRelatedToID($id)}");
$res = odbc_execute($stmt, array());

//or

$stmt = odbc_prepare($con, "{CALL usp_GetRelatedToID(?)}");
$res = odbc_execute($stmt, array($id));
```

Both return this error message:

```
Warning: odbc_execute() [function.odbc-execute]: 
    SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Cursor type changed, 
    SQL state 01S02 in SQLExecute
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well. The way I got around it was to use

```
odbc_exec($connection, $sql)
```

Instead of

```
odbc_execute($connection, $sql)
```

Per a user comment [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-setoption.php#88295)

Comment was:

> BTW. If anyone is banging his head about "cursor type changed" warning
> while using     execute with ORDER BY clause, then just use exec for
> now (remember to addslashes for yourself).
>
> In PHP 5.3 a Bug #43668
> will be fixed and it will allow you to change a cursor type to
> SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC
>
> Note that you could also try to select a cursor type in odbc_connect, but that didn't work for me (much more problems appeared then it solved).

Apparently this is a bug in PHP, and will be patched per [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43668)

So try using odbc_exec() insted of odbc_execute() if you are having this problem.

Comment: Wow, better late than never. It worked like a charm! Much better than my solution where I have to rearrange the order of the columns. Thanks :D

Comment: No problem! I really was banging my head against the wall with the stupid cursor errors, and so I spent a day looking.