# PHP - call SQL Server procedure via ODBC error

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, odbc

Ugh. I've spent hours searching for a solution for this, so it's probably something simple. I have a stored procedure in SQL Server (2008) that I'm trying to call from PHP code. I'm using ODBC, and everything works if I use a hard-coded SQL statement.

But I'm trying to call a stored procedure that returns a set of rows (cursor, dataset, etc.), passing two parameters. When I run the code through my browser I just get a 500 http error. It is bombing on the odbc_execute() line. Here's my code:

```
// DSN-less connection:
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=$server;Database=$database;", '', '');
if (!$conn)
   {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
$fromDate = new DateTime('2012-1-1');
$toDate = new DateTime('2013-12-31');

$sql = odbc_prepare($conn, "{call GET_EVENTS_BY_DATE_RANGE(?, ?)}");
$params = array($fromDate, $toDate);

$result = odbc_execute($sql, $params);  
if ( $result === false)
{
exit("Query failed");
}

odbc_close($conn);
```

Again, no problems until it hits the odbc_execute() function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want help with this, you need to provide more information than "500 error" - this is a generic, friendly error - you need to turn off friendly errors and find out what the actual error is...

Comment: Crap, you're right. Sorry. Here's the error: `PHP Warning:  odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Cursor type changed, SQL state 01S02 in SQLExecute in C:\bleah\sp.php on line 24`

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011526/calling-odbc-fetch-array-after-executing-a-stored-procedure-in-php-gives-error

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff That was a good link, thanks, but the solution(s) that worked for that person (using odbc_exec instead of odbc_execute) returned a different error for me (warning, actually): `odbc_exec() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\...`.